# Android studio layout xml files code changes automatically from default

Tags: android, xml, android-studio

I am facing this problem while my code of xml layout file changed from this

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?><RelativeLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
xmlns:app="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res-auto"
android:layout_width="match_parent"
android:layout_height="wrap_content"
android:background="@drawable/divider_using_border"/>
```

to that one

```
`<component name="ProjectCodeStyleConfiguration">
<code_scheme name="Project" version="173">
<Objective-C-extensions>
  <file>
    <option name="com.jetbrains.cidr.lang.util.OCDeclarationKind" value="Import" />
    <option name="com.jetbrains.cidr.lang.util.OCDeclarationKind"value="Macro"/>
    <option name="com.jetbrains.cidr.lang.util.OCDeclarationKind"value="Typedef"/>
    <option name="com.jetbrains.cidr.lang.util.OCDeclarationKind" value="Enum" />
    <option name="com.jetbrains.cidr.lang.util.OCDeclarationKind" value="Constant" />
    <option name="com.jetbrains.cidr.lang.util.OCDeclarationKind" value="Global" />
    <option name="com.jetbrains.cidr.lang.util.OCDeclarationKind" value="Struct" />
    <option name="com.jetbrains.cidr.lang.util.OCDeclarationKind" value="FunctionPredecl" />
    <option name="com.jetbrains.cidr.lang.util.OCDeclarationKind" value="Function" />
  </file>
  <class>
    <option name="com.jetbrains.cidr.lang.util.OCDeclarationKind" value="Property" />
    <option name="com.jetbrains.cidr.lang.util.OCDeclarationKind" value="Synthesize" />
    <option name="com.jetbrains.cidr.lang.util.OCDeclarationKind" value="InitMethod" />
    <option name="com.jetbrains.cidr.lang.util.OCDeclarationKind" value="StaticMethod" />
    <option name="com.jetbrains.cidr.lang.util.OCDeclarationKind" value="InstanceMethod" />
    <option name="com.jetbrains.cidr.lang.util.OCDeclarationKind" value="DeallocMethod" />
  </class>
  <extensions>
    <pair source="cpp" header="h" fileNamingConvention="NONE" />
    <pair source="c" header="h" fileNamingConvention="NONE" />
  </extensions>
</Objective-C-extensions>
</code_scheme>
    </component>`
```

This is happening with many files. Apart from this my application runs perfect without any crash.

Comment: do you have Android NDK Support Plugin in Android Studio?

Comment: @MustafaBohra no

Comment: please check it in File>Setting>Plugins .. i think it is installed by default

Comment: @MustafaBohra  yes i had installed i check this so now what should i suppose to do

Comment: try to disable this plugin and and than restart android studio and see if this problem still occured

Comment: @MustafaBohra thank you but problem still remains

Comment: have you find any solution?

Answer (score 0):

Disable th NDK plug-in and Restart Android Studio it worked for me.

Answer (score 0):

I faced similar problem where some of my xml codes were replaced by random java code in Android Studio IDE but these xml files were intact when I opened them in notepad.

Here is what worked for me --

1. Close Android studio.
2. Go to C:\Users\*username*\.AndroidStudio4.0\system\caches.
3. Delete all files in this location.
4. Open your Android Studio again.

I was working on 3 projects simultaneously (I wonder if that's the reason).